# Cocos2d : dealloc is not called after calling release

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Dealloc is not called even after release. Here is my code for initialization.

```
@interface PPTileMap : CCTMXTiledMap 
{

}
@end

@implementation PPTileMap

-(void)dealloc
{
    printf("Dealloc called\n");
}
@end

//allocation
PPTileMap *tileMap = [[PPTileMap alloc] initWithTMXFile:tilemapFile];

//release
[tileMap release];
tileMap = nil;
```

When I use tiledMapWithTMXFile then it will..but crashes after loading thread.
Why dealloc is not called for above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason that `dealoc` is not called after sending `release` that the object is retained by someone else (added to NSArray or NSDictionary, retained by one of your objects, you have run action on it, etc.). If you don't know, what object retains your object, override it's `retain` method as

```
- (id) retain
{
    return [super retain];
}
```

Then place breakpoint inside this method. Then you will be able to see the call stack every time something want to retain your object. You can also override `release` method

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved this problem. Special thanks to Morion. 
Here I explicitly used removeFromParentAndCleanup and then dealloc is called.

```
//release

[tileMap removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
[tileMap release];
tileMap = nil;
```