# CCParticleSystemQuad not getting deallocated when added to a moving sprite

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

I am trying to add a particle trail effect in cocos2d, I managed to do it by adding CCParticleSystemQuad emitter as a child to the moving sprite.
But I am observing that this emitter is not getting deallocated eventually.

if I add this emitter to same sprite, but keep it still and dont move at all, emitter does get deallocated.

I cant figure out why this is happening..

code is somewhat like this..

```
CCParticleSystemQuad *emitter = [[[CCParticleSystemQuad alloc] initWithFile:@"myEffect.plist"] autorelease];
emitter.positionType = kCCPositionTypeFree;
emitter.autoRemoveOnFinish = YES;
[movingSprite addChild:emitter z:movingSprite.zOrder + 1000];
```

Comment: does movingSprite get deallocated?

Comment: yes, the sprite does get deallocated in both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you called `[emitter removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];`

Here is one of my [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101400/cocos2d-dealloc-is-not-called-after-calling-release)

Find out where object is retained, follow Morion's answer in above thread.

Quick Solution:

```
CCParticleSystemQuad *emitter = [CCParticleSystemQuad particleWithFile:@"myEffect.plist"];
emitter.positionType = kCCPositionTypeFree;
emitter.autoRemoveOnFinish = YES;
[movingSprite addChild:emitter z:movingSprite.zOrder + 1000];

//To remove
[emitter stopSystem];
[emitter removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
```

Comment: The reason why this was happening was that I was calling [movingSprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:NO] when I was done moving, but the duration of emitter was longer than that, so emitter's action wasn't removed and hence it wasn't deallocated. I should either call  [movingSprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES] or do the above.. thanks  it is clear to me now.